# Powershell: Specify file path as variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, powershell, csv, powershell-ise

I am running the following SQL query through a powershell script and need to run the script multiple times against different files. So what I am trying to figure out is how to specify a file path as a variable when I run the script?

```
update [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable]
set [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Wave = 'Wave1.1'
from [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable]
inner join OPENROWSET(BULK 'FilePath\file.csv',    
FORMATFILE= 'E:\import.xml') AS a
on ([$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Name= a.Name) and  
([$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Domain = a.Domain)
```

The 'FilePath\file.csv' is the file path I need to define as a variable so that my code would instead look like this:

```
inner join OPENROWSET(BULK '$INPUTFILEPATH',    
FORMATFILE= 'E:\import.xml') AS a
```

Any help or potentially better methods to accomplish this would help very much.

From the command like I want to be able to run the script like this:

CMD: updatescript.ps1 $INPUTFILEPATH = C:\Documents\myfile.csv

Again, I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there.
You will need to add a parameter block at the very start of your script e.g.

```
Param( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'leaf'})]  
[string] $InputFilePath  
)
```

This creates a mandatory (not optional) string parameter, called `InputFilePath`, and the `ValidateScript` is code used to validate the parameter, in this case checking the file exists using the `Test-Path` cmdlet and pathtype of leaf (if checking existence of a directory use `'container'`).

When running your script use the syntax below:

```
updatescript.ps1 -INPUTFILEPATH "C:\Documents\myfile.csv"
```

and in the script use the variable as the path exactly as in your question:

```
inner join OPENROWSET(BULK '$INPUTFILEPATH',    
FORMATFILE= 'E:\import.xml') AS a
```

**NOTE:** in powershell when using parameters when running a script you only need to use the least amount of characters that uniquely identify that parameter from all the others in your param block - in this case `-I` works just as well as `-InputFilePath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass command line parameters to the powershell script using `param`.

Example:

```
param(
   [string]$INPUTFILEPATH
)
```

And then call the script as follows:

```
updatescript.ps1 -INPUTFILEPATH C:\Documents\myfile.csv
```

More details about cmd line parameters can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/jj554301.aspx)